# Azure DevOps Web Hooks - How to limit history/logging

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-server, azure-devops-server-2020

I started using `Web Hooks` in Azure DevOps and was curious, if there's a way to **limit history** to an x amount of days/events and/or disable `Detailed logging`.

I subscribed to events like `Build completed` and `Work item updated`, which are generating a lotta data and I don't want to keep them forever.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Can you share your notification screenshot to let me know more about it. By default, using WebHook does not send you notifications. I guess if you created a custom notification, if so, you can turn off the notification according to the documentation [Unsubscribe or opt out of a team or out-of-box (OOB) notification subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/notifications/manage-your-personal-notifications?view=azure-devops&tabs=new-account-enabled#unsubscribe-or-opt-out-of-a-team-or-out-of-box-oob-notification-subscription).

Comment: @ZiyangLiu-MSFT *Notification* might have been the wrong term. What I actually meant is *events*. I edited my original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently DevOps does not support limiting service hooks history. The Service Hooks page in the web access admin shows your recent activity (last 14 days) for each subscription, and whether a subscription is enabled, disabled, or restricted.

If you want to limit the number of notifications displayed on the current page, you can use the tab shown in the figure.

[image]

If you want to limit the data storage of history for notification (activity), it is recommended that you could submit a feature request on:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion. Voting helps increase the priority of the issue by consolidating customer impact under one feedback.